# use v-btn 'loading' inside v-data-table

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

A naive, non-working attempt:

```
<v-btn class="btn-primary" @click="invite(props.item)" v-if="props.item.status 
== 'NEW'" :loading="'loading'+props.item.id" @click.native="loader = 
'loading'+props.item.id">
{{ $t("message.invite") }}
</v-btn>
```

It appears this fails because the result inside ":loading" becomes a string - it needs to be a boolean variable. So how do I dynamically reference a boolean "loading" based on the "id" of that row?

The above works fine if I just use the normal:

```
loading="loading"
```

but needs to be:

```
loading="loading123"
```

where 123 is props.item.id

Comment: Do you have a property named `loading` having a boolena valur in your `data` section. Otherwise, `:loading="loading"` should not work neither. If so, please share your code inside `<script>` tag, too.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
:loading="loading[props.index]" @click.native="loader = 'loading[props.index]'"
```

so an array of booleans obviously.